# How to create loading dialogs in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, progress-bar

Those dark spinning progress dialogs in the Amazon and Engadget apps - are those standard in Android?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

It's a ProgressDialog, with setIndeterminate(true).

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

An indeterminate progress bar doesn't actually show a bar, it shows a spinning activity circle thing.  I'm sure you know what I mean :)

Comment: ProgressDialog is discouraged. According to the link you posted: "Avoid ProgressDialog. [...] If you need to indicate loading or indeterminate progress, you should instead follow the design guidelines for Progress & Activity and use a ProgressBar in your layout."

Comment: Currently, ProgressDialog has been taken out of the docs and the solution does not appear to be viable any longer.

Comment: To dismiss the dialog, use `dialog.dismiss();`

Comment: ProgressDialog is now deprecated, check this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351516/5090196

Answer (score 36):

Today things have changed a little.

Now we avoid use ProgressDialog to show spinning progress:

[image]

If you want to put in your app a spinning progress you should use an Activity indicators:

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html#activity

---

## Update

Thay have renamed the component to Progress Indicators now.

The new link for reference is: https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android

Comment: Take a look here to see how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316365/how-can-i-display-a-holo-themed-activity-circle

Comment: @Rafael Miceli Your reference goes to 404 - Page Not Found