# How can I display a holo-themed activity circle?

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I've tried to show an indeterminate activity circle like this one:

[image]

Here's the layout code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Here's the styling code:

```
<style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
</style>
```

My circle doesn't look anything like the Holo themed circle that you see in the Gmail App or the Play app. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the nice Holo animated activity circle?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This really wasn't documented anywhere and I found it through some random article. Adding this styling attribute does the trick:

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
```

The only reference to this on the developer documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#progressBarStyleLarge).

Comment: I wish I could vote several times for this. Actually you can make platform-specific reference for a lot more than only activity circle. Just check a full list list of of [android attributes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html)

Answer (score 20):

Your first layout was right but you chose the wrong style. The right one is:

```
style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
```

Comment: This one should be accepted answer, more specific on the styling

Answer (score 2):

What version of Android are you using? If you're not using a version with Holo, you won't be able to display things using the Holo style. A solution to that is to use a library like ActionBarSherlock, which backports the Holo theme to previous Android versions.

Comment: I'm using API15. I guess that's 4.0.4.

Comment: I think my code itself is wrong. I'm using the wrong style I guess.

Comment: AFAIK, Holo can still be used, but it is an outdated style.